# Null Value in bundle = this.getArguments() method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to send some data from main activity to it's child fragments class. I have used below code but still getting `null` value in `getarguments()` method. I have debugged also but no luck .

```
    setupToolbar();
    setupViewPager();
    setprofiledata();
    setupCollapsingToolbar();
    // setupDrawer();


private void setprofiledata() {
    String tag_string_req = "req_profile";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
            Toast.makeText(Profile.this,"Login done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                // boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
            /*    if (!error) {*/
                // user successfully logged in
                // Create login session


                // Now store the user in SQLite
                //String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("param");

                JSONObject jsonObject = user.getJSONObject("details");

                Log.d("Personal info",jsonObject.toString());

                String name = jsonObject.getString("Name");
                String email = jsonObject.getString("Email");
                String Contact = jsonObject.getString("Contact No.");
                String gender = jsonObject.getString("Gender");
                String Country =jsonObject.getString("Country");
                String City = jsonObject.getString("City");
                String State = jsonObject.getString("State");
                String Zip = jsonObject.getString("Zip");
                String Birth_Date = jsonObject.getString("Birth Date");
                String Status = jsonObject.getString("Status");
                String Connects_in= jsonObject.getString("Connects in");


                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("name", name);
      // set Fragmentclass Arguments
                TabFragment tab1 = new TabFragment();
                tab1.setArguments(bundle);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("visitor_id", "14");
            params.put("request","Dashboard_VisitorInfo");

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

 /*private void setupDrawer() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

}*/

private void setupCollapsingToolbar() {
    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(
            R.id.collapse_toolbar);

    collapsingToolbar.setTitleEnabled(false);
}

private void setupViewPager() {
  //  final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
   viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TabbedCoordinatorLayout");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new TabFragment(), "Personal");
    adapter.addFrag(new Tab1(), "Commnication");
    adapter.addFrag(new Tab2(), "Notes");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

And getting values in fregment class like this

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    nameedit = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editnameid);
    if (bundle != null){
        String name=bundle.getString("name");

        nameedit.setText(name);
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand your code ? Only fragments created inside `setupViewPager` are used. And they are without arguments ... `tab1` is not used at all

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow , it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

You are passing arguments after network response but you are initialising the ViewPager Adapter prior to that. Because of which you are getting null in Fragment.

What you can do is simple get the fragment object from viewPagerAdapter and then set the `Arguments` to it.

use `getItem(int position)` method of view pager It would return you the fragment object and then assign `Arguments` to it.